# Django - using management and sharing data

Tags: python, django, multithreading, singleton, django-management-command

I am using Django (1.9) and I'd like to share class object between management commands.

Let's say - to be simple - that I have a main app which instanciates some classes.

```
my_main_app/commands/mananagement/setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from django.core.management import base, call_command
from somewhere import SingletonClass

class Command(base.BaseCommand):
    '''
       Overloads runserver command by creating a few extra objects
    '''
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        myObject = SingletonClass(date = datetime.now())
        call_command("runserver") # this doesn't return
```

What I want is to access the "myObject" object within another command line call. For instance, I'd like to know when the myObject object was instanciated.

```
my_other_app/commands/mananagement/command.py
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from django.core.management import base, call_command
from somewhere import SingletonClass

class Command(base.BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        myObject = SingletonClass() # <- this should be the same instance than the object created in the main app
        return myObject.date # must return the date of the call to the setup command
```

In the example I use Singleton pattern because it seems to be close to what I want.

So far I found only the following solution:

1) The main app creates a server listening to command line calls

```
from somewhere import SingletonClass, Server
class Command(base.BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.myObject = SingletonClass(date = datetime.now())
        self.__server = Server(handler = self.handle_distant)
        self.__server.start() # this starts a listening server

    def handle_distant(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
            this method is called from distant
            client calls
        '''
        return call_command(*args, **kwargs)
```

2) The other app is a client of that server:

```
from somewhere import SingletonClass, Client
class Command(base.BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options["local"] = True: # wil be True when called from the main app
            return SingletonClass().date
        else:
            client = Client()
            options["local"] = True
            return client.doSomething(*args, **options)
```

This can work but I have a manually serialize (on the client side) & deserialize (on the server side) each command. I find it ugly and I wonder if there is a best way to use Django.

I could also use the database to store every single object I want to share but it doesn't seem better.

**Real use case below**:

For example, I have an app called "Configuration" which is able to load properties files on the file system. (note: I call property file like presented here: docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). This app loads the properties files when the user run the command "load-config". Then, I expect all my apps to have access to the configuration previously loaded without having to re-read each property file. I want to instanciate a "PropertyManager" object once for all my apps. So far, I'm storing the properties read in the database so that every app can get it from there

Any comment or ideas?

Comment: I think you're going to have to give more details of your use case. Management commands by definition are for short one-off tasks; they run in their own process and don't share data with anything else, so this isn't normally something you'd want to do. Exactly what data are you trying to share?

Comment: For example, I have an app called "Configuration" which is able to load properties files on the file system. (note: I call property file like presented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). This app loads the properties files when the user run the command "load-config". Then, I expect all my apps to have access to the configuration previously loaded without having to re-read each property file. I want to instanciate a "PropertyManager" object once for all my apps. So far, I'm storing the properties read in the database so that every app can get it from there